# aggrid detailgrid row update with immutableData=true does not work

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, master-detail

I use aggdrid 24.1.0 with react and I notice a possible problem.

If I use detail CellRenderer with immutableData resolved to true , the state inside the detail grid will not be updated instantly, but it will take a few seconds.

Reading the source code in instantService I've read that the detail grid state updates lazily.
Does anyone know how to disable it or change this lazy time?